# Extract clusters of similar continuous numbers from vectors

Tags: r

I am attempting an analysis that requires the extraction of a some (2 or 3) consecutive values in which perform further analysis later.

I have two vectors: *a* is the output from a machine of consecutive cellular signals. *b* is the same output, but shifted by 1. This notation is used to understand the variability between one signal and the next one

```
a <- c(150, 130, 135, 180, 182, 190, 188, 195, 170, 140, 120, 130, 180, 181)
b <- c(130, 135, 180, 182, 190, 188, 195, 170, 140, 120, 130, 180, 181, 130)
```

What I am trying to do is to identify the most homogeneous (stable) region (i.e. one value is similar to the following) in this set of data.

The idea I had was to perform a subtraction between `a` and `b` and consider the absolute value:

```
c <- abs(a-b)
```

which gives

```
c

 [1] 20  5 45  2  8  2  7 25 30 20 10 50  1 51
```

Now, if I want the 3 closest consecutive points, I can clearly see that the sequence `2 8 2` is by far the one that I would consider, but I have no idea on how I can automatically extract these 3 values, especially from arrays of hundreds of data points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initial data:

```
a <- c(150, 130, 135, 180, 182, 190, 188, 195, 170, 140, 120, 130, 180, 181)
b <- c(130, 135, 180, 182, 190, 188, 195, 170, 140, 120, 130, 180, 181, 130)
```

Find absolute difference between two vectors:

```
res <- abs(a - b)
```

For each element in `res` get neighbors and calculate sum off absolute difference :

```
# with res[(x-1):(x+1)] we extract x and it's neighbors 
resSimilarity <- sapply(seq_along(res), function(x) sum(res[(x-1):(x+1)]))

resPosition <- which.min(resSimilarity)
# [1] 5
```

To extract values from original vectors use:

```
a[(resPosition - 1):(resPosition + 1)]
# [1] 180 182 190
b[(resPosition - 1):(resPosition + 1)]
# [1] 182 190 188
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I probably put the question in the wrong way. With the method you suggested, I could obtain 8, while I would have liked to obtain the original values (i.e. 180, 182, 190) or their position in the vector, so I could use their position to extract the values that are in a "steady state" zone in the trace I am analysing. Would that be possible?

Answer (score 1):

Here is one more alternative:

```
a <- c(150, 130, 135, 180, 182, 190, 188, 195, 170, 140, 120, 130, 180, 181)
b <- c(130, 135, 180, 182, 190, 188, 195, 170, 140, 120, 130, 180, 181, 130)

res <- abs(a-b)

> which.min(diff(c(0, cumsum(res)), lag=3))
[1] 4
> res[(4):(4+2)]
[1] 2 8 2
```

The above code uses `cumsum` to get the cumulative sums of your absolute differences. Then it calls `diff` with `lag=3` to get the differences between each element and the element 3 positions away from it. Finally it takes the position where the increase in cumulative sum over successive 3 elements was the smallest.

Comment: Hi, this does not give me the same output you get.
I obtain "1" from the "which.min(c(0, diff(cumsum(res)), lag=3))" command, not "4"

Comment: @Mollan sorry, added one `)` at the wrong place, should be correct now.

Comment: Thank you, it worked. With a few addition to your code I could extract the positions in the original vector :) Thanks!